# Codeigniter Mysql Don't complete cycle

Tags: php, mysql, odbc, xampp, codeigniter-2

I'm having some kind of problem and i don't know how i solve it.

The problem is, that i have 500 registers in another database, and the query to get them its has them all, but when i do the cycle to insert/update them in m y database the foreach cycle don't reach the end and it doesn't show any error.

Here is the cycle:

```
foreach ($this->getMetaEmpregado()->getAll()->result_array() as $modelData) {
        $oEmpregado = $this->getEmpregadoObject($modelData);

        $arrayEmpWhere = array(
            'idempregado' => $oEmpregado->getIdEmpregado(),
            'idsociedade' => $oEmpregado->getIdSociedade(),
            'nif' => $oEmpregado->getNif()
        );

        if ($this->getWayUtilizador()->get($arrayEmpWhere)->num_rows() == 0) {
            $countInsert++;
            $this->insertNewEmp($oEmpregado);
        } else {
            $countUpdate++;
            $this->UpdateEmp($oEmpregado);
        }
    }

echo "Total Updates: $countUpdate Total Inserts: $countInsert<br>";
```

It down't shoe the echo in the end because its stops around the 260 register, but sometimes it reaches the 300 others not even 100.

Regards,
Elkas

Comment: You need to increase the execution time of your php script

Comment: Try to enable all errors on your development server. This will tell you what's going wrong, script runs too long/runs out of memory. Maybe even throw in xdebug in there and see what's happening with the loop data.

Comment: I just found out why it was doing it wrong. It was a DEFINE variable with 10 secs used a long time ago... but this project used a lot of more data and the connection much slower. 10 seconds isn't enough.
Marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `script` is `taking too long`, You need to `increase` the `Max_Execution_Time` in your **php.ini**.

You can use **ini_set method** to change it, like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have it at 120, but the script runs for like 10/20 secs. But I'll try it.